# Mysql insert issue with chracters from my mother language

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am trying to insert data from my mother language (Sinhala) into my mysql table. But `MySQL` displays my chracters as question marks.

This is how I test it:

```
CREATE DATABASE sinhala_test;
USE kindheart;

ALTER DATABASE sinhala_test
CHARACTER SET  utf8  
COLLATE utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_si` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description_si` TEXT COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_update` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `category` VALUES (1,'පොත් පත් සහ පාසල් උපකරණ','නවතම පොත් පත් අවශ්‍යතා ඇතුළු සියළුම පාසැල් හා අධ්‍යාපන මෙවලම්.',NOW());
```

This is what can I get from MySQL command line:

```
mysql> select * from category\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   category_id: 1
       name_si: ???? ??? ?? ????? ?????
description_si: ???? ??????? ????/ ?????? ?? ?? ???? O/L, A/L ??????? ?????, ???????, ??????? ????? ?????? ???? ??? ????????. ????/???????/???????????/??????/?????? ????/ ????/????/?????? ????? ?????? ?????? ?? ???????? ??????.
   last_update: 2018-05-20 11:11:20
```

Can anybody tell me how can I fix this problem?

`NOTE:` When inserting from `phpMyAdmin` its correctly work.

Comment: You should say what OS you're using

Comment: I am using windows OS..

Comment: What collation are you using when establishing PHP's connection to the database server?

Comment: See "question marks" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored